# i have a soundTransform issue.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, mute

i know i'm missing something stupid here. can someone give a hand? i'm trying to mute and make mcs invisible. i've done something wrong with the soundtransform bit. quite new on AS3.

```
var isPlayingMC:MovieClip =mc1;; 
var isPlayingMCcurrentFrame = 0;

var soundTr:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
soundTr.volume = 1;

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMC1); 
function playMC1(e:MouseEvent):void {

    isPlayingMCcurrentFrame = isPlayingMC.currentFrame; 
    isPlayingMC = mc1; 
    isPlayingMC.gotoAndPlay(isPlayingMCcurrentFrame);
    mc2.volume = 0;
    mc3.volume = 0;
    mc3.visible = false;
    mc2.visible = false;
    mc1.visible = true
}

btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMC2); 
function playMC2(e:MouseEvent):void {

    isPlayingMCcurrentFrame = isPlayingMC.currentFrame; 
    isPlayingMC = mc2; 
    isPlayingMC.gotoAndPlay(isPlayingMCcurrentFrame);
    mc1.volume = 0;
    mc3.volume = 0;
    mc1.visible = false;
    mc3.visible = false;
    mc2.visible = true

} 
Btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMC3); 
function playMC3(e:MouseEvent):void {
    isPlayingMCcurrentFrame = isPlayingMC.currentFrame; 
    isPlayingMC = mc3; 
    isPlayingMC.gotoAndPlay(isPlayingMCcurrentFrame);
    mc1.volume = 0;
    mc2.volume = 0;
    mc1.visible = false;
    mc2.visible = false;
    mc3.visible = true
    }
```

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of the problem you are having. I'm looking at the code and I'm not sure where you are having the problem.

Comment: the mute doesn;t work. ex.. if mc2 is playing and i press btn3, mc2 keeps playing as well as mc3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually apply your `SoundTransform` to the `MovieClip`s, as they don't have a simple `volume` property:

```
var st1:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
st1.volume = 0;
mc1.soundTransform = st1;
```

[Here's](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#soundTransform) the relevant reference document.